# nginx + mysql + hhvm + phpmyadmin - Stuck after login page all blank and token in the url

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, hhvm

nginx + mysql 5.5 + hhvm on ubuntu 14.10 works fine. 
I installed phpmyadmin with: `sudo apt-get phpmyadmin` and I have this version: 4.2.6-1.

After the login page from phpmyadmin I get a blank page something like this in the url: `/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=7e858f9ed3b783b34d4c2274d721f125&SID`

I get this error message in the hhvm error log:

> \nFatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Port is
>   not numeric' in :\nStack trace:\n#0 (): mysqli->real_connect()\n#1
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php(114):
>   mysqli_real_connect()\n#2
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php(191):
>   PMA_DBI_Mysqli->_realConnect()\n#3
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php(2078):
>   PMA_DBI_Mysqli->connect()\n#4
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(978):
>   PMA_DatabaseInterface->connect()\n#5
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(12): include()\n#6 {main}

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Easy fix, simply open "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php" 
and find

```
require_once './libraries/logging.lib.php';
```

replace it with the following...

```
$GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['port']=3306;
require_once './libraries/logging.lib.php';
```

Comment: THIS! Of all the answers I found that did not work, this was the one that actually did. Thank you.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer a thousand times. This, contrary to all other solutions I have found, actually worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

simply go to terminal and give command

**vi etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php**

change **$dbport = ''** to **$dbport = '3306'**

refresh your phpmyadmin page. it should work. it worked for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me, THANKS!